# Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 error '80040e14'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am getting this error when running my asp page. I am using sql server 2012.

Here is the full error:

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 error '80040e14'
>
> Incorrect syntax near '44447'.
>
> /Applications/SLS_Forum/post_info.asp, line 889

This is line 889:

```
my_Conn.Execute (strSql),,adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
```

This is my SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO FORUM_TOPICS (FORUM_ID, CAT_ID, T_SUBJECT, T_MESSAGE, T_AUTHOR, T_LAST_POST, T_LAST_POST_AUTHOR, T_LAST_POST_REPLY_ID, T_DATE, T_STATUS, T_IP, T_STICKY, T_SIG, T_ARCHIVE_FLAG, T_REPLIES, T_UREPLIES) 
VALUES (5, 4, 'Test', 'Test', 544, '20180608152613', 544, 0, '20180608152613', 1, '172.20.30.161', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

The point of the page is to create a forum post, although it gives me this error, it still creates the post though. I'm not really sure what's going on, can anyone help? Let me know if you need anymore information. Thanks in advance for the responses.

Comment: It could be a compatibility issue, can you check this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/966146/run-time-error-2147217900-80040e14 and follow the steps there?

Comment: @endo64 I did that, but in the options menu I can only change the compatibility to 90,100, or 110. 80 isn't an option

Comment: Does same error happen if you write that SQL statement into Management Studio or it happens only if you executed it from ASP page? If latter, is that the exact SQL, no parameters no concatenation?

Comment: @endo64 It gives me the same error if i execute it in Management Studio as well

Comment: Check if there's a trigger on `FORUM_TOPICS` that could cause this error indirectly. Your main query text doesn't contain `44447`, after all.

Comment: @endo64 good call! i found this in the trigger: RAISERROR 44447 'The record can''t be added or changed. Referential integrity rules require a related record in table ''FORUM_MEMBERS''.'

Comment: Credit should go to @JeroenMostert not me :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert just noticed you were the one who spotted that. Thanks! this solved my issues if you would like to make it an answer

Comment: Now appreciate the delicious irony of someone making an error in the statement that was supposed to handle an error... [`RAISERROR` needs commas between the arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql), and `44447` is only valid if it was added as a custom message anyway. But even more fundamentally -- this should have been handled with a foreign key constraint, not a trigger.